# Why aren't my index documents fetchable by id after restoring a snapshot from ES 6.4.2 in ES 7.6.1?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

After upgrading my ES cluster from 6.4.2 to 7.6.1 and restoring the old cluster's snapshot, documents on a few given indices stopped being fetchable by id.

This doesn't work after restoring the snapshot.

```
GET myindex/_doc/c1d89b00-d030-11e3-bd52-f3718ac695f3
```

If I duplicate the document:

```
PUT myindex/_doc/c1d89b00-d030-11e3-bd52-f3718ac695f3
{
   "name" : "dogs and cats",
   "notes" : "Imported",
   "myid" : "c1d89b00-d030-11e3-bd52-f3718ac695f3" // yes, it's redundant
}
```

This suddenly works:

```
GET myindex/_doc/c1d89b00-d030-11e3-bd52-f3718ac695f3
```

**However, now I have two documents with the same ID.**

(updating doesn't work, because the doc is not fetcheable by ID)

Index definition:

```
GET myindex
{
  "myindex" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "merge_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "index_ngram",
          "search_analyzer" : "search_ngram"
        },
        "notes" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "index_ngram",
          "search_analyzer" : "search_ngram"
        },
        "myid" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "max_ngram_diff" : "48",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "provided_name" : "myindex",
        "creation_date" : "1584420860612",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "my_ngram" : {
              "type" : "ngram",
              "min_gram" : "2",
              "max_gram" : "50"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "index_ngram" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "my_ngram"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "keyword"
            },
            "default" : {
              "tokenizer" : "keyword"
            },
            "search_ngram" : {
              "filter" : "lowercase",
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "uuid" : "uyp_WK3xRjucFRGhYDHbcQ",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7060199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The most interesting part is that I have other indices (using a different id format), which had their data restored from the same snapshot, which their docs continued to be fetchable by id after the upgrade.

Comment: I also already tried reindexing the docs to another index, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, after restoring the old cluster's snapshot, the issue of not being able to GET docs by their ids seems to be related to the number of shards used on that index.

So shrinking the index into a new one, using a single shard like shown below, fixes the issue:

```
PUT /myindex/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": "instance-0000000000", 
    "index.blocks.write": true 
  }
}

POST myindex/_shrink/myindex_shrinked
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.number_of_shards": 1, 
    "index.codec": "best_compression" 
  },
  "aliases": {
    "my_search_indices": {}
  }
}

PUT /myindex_shrinked/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": null, 
    "index.blocks.write": true 
  }
}
```